# Как убрать предупреждение 'Cannot resolve file' в тэге 'a href' файла jsp?

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, jsp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему анализатор выдаёт предупреждение на значения ссылок (`a href = ссылка`) в файле jsp?
Например:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
            <jsp:useBean id="item" type="entity.Item"/>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="item?id=${item.id}&action=view">${item.title}</a></td>                    
                <td><%=CurrencyFormat.format(item.getPrice())%></td>
                <c:if test="${role == 'admin'}">                        
                    <td>${item.amount}</td>
                    <td><a href="item?id=${item.id}&action=delete">Delete</a></td>
                    <td><a href="item?id=${item.id}&action=edit">Edit</a></td>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${role == 'user'}">
                    <td><a href="item?id=${item.id}&action=buy">Buy</a></td>
                </c:if>
            </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Здесь в строках `<a href="item?id...` подчёркивается слово `item` и выдаётся предупреждение `Cannot resolve file 'item'`. При этом приложение успешно компилируется и работает. Как устранить предупреждение, не отключая и не подавляя инспекцию?

Comment: Создай файл с таким именем.

Comment: @Roman, работает, но не нравится мне заводить пустые файлы только для того, чтобы инспекция заткнулась.

Comment: @Roman, разобрался, нужно было сделать маппинг сервлета на этот ресурс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы убрать это предупреждение, нужно сделать маппинг сервлета на этот ресурс в файле `web.xml`.
Например, вот такой код `<a href="items">Webstore</a>` не будет содержать ошибок (слово `items` не подчеркивается анализатором), если в `web.xml` прописать следующее:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ItemServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.ItemServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>    

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ItemServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/items</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Разумеется, для маппинга также можно использовать аннотацию `@WebServlet("/items")`  вместо `web.xml`:

```
@WebServlet("/items")
public class ItemServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```